# Removing UIGestureRecognizer does not work

Tags: ios, gesture

I already searched in Stackoverflow and cannot find the answer for this specific combination of SWRevealController and UIGestureRecognizer.

In my iOS project I added a UIGestureRecognizer to open the Facebook like Menu with pan gesture. For the Facebook-like menu I m using the SWRevealController library: [John-Lluch's SWRevealController library](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController).

I also successfully added the UIGestureRecognizer with

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

It is working fine. Now the problem that I am facing, I try to remove this panGestureRecognizer depending if the user is logged in or not. However, both of the following seems not work:

```
 [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:nil];
 [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

How can I remove it again, please help! (I hope I gave enough information, otherwise let me know! Thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.view.gestureRecognizers) {
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karthik, I tried that as well but it actually also removes the scroll functionality, so I cannot scroll down the feed (similar to Instagram) that I am using. Any other ideas?

Comment: then do some simple take the some str or user preference value and check that condition is yes show the sidemenu else part show all value as nil

Answer (score 0):

Its very strange and I came to the following solution that seems to work, thanks to Karthik's tips. However, I still consider it as sub-optimal:

```
bool found = false;
        for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.view.gestureRecognizers) {
            if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[recognizer class]] isEqualToString:@"UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer"]){
                [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
                found = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (!found && self.view.gestureRecognizers.count > 1) {
            [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code solved my problem,

```
while (myView.gestureRecognizers.count) {
    [myView removeGestureRecognizer:[myView.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```